# Find first empty row, copy & paste values up to that row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a Google app script that would copy all of the data in columns B through D, **up to the first empty row**, and then paste it in the same place as static values. Column A needs to remain dynamic (indexes list of names from a different tab). Please see attached screenshot.

What is the easiest way to do this?

**Thanks in advance for your help!**

[Screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epCBm.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Can you share a copy of your script as it stands now?  And please describe the particular problem that you having with it.

Comment: If you're looking for the next empty row in a sheet take a look at [sheet.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow()).  All you have to do is add one to it and your on the next row.

Comment: Just updated the post and added a screenshot. Thanks for your help!